# How do I give a Player money when they kill someone else?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know how to give a player money whenever they kill someone else with commands. I want it for my server. How can I do this?

Comment: Money, as in, a scoreboard objective? Or like emeralds or gold?

Comment: what kind of money are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to create a scoreboard to keep track of when a player kills another player. Run this command once to create a scoreboard that goes up by one every time a player kills another player.

```
/scoreboard objectives add pvpKill playerKillCount
```

Then on a clock run these two commands to give a player a diamond when they have a kill, and then reset their player kill score

```
/give @a[score_pvpKill_min=1] minecraft:diamond
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_pvpKill_min=1] pvpKill 1
```

If you're creating a virtual currency you would need to run this command once too

```
/scoreboard objectives add money dummy
```

Run this once for each player to give them a starting score of 0 (assuming they're not all online at the same time)

```
/scoreboard players add @a money 0
```

Then instead of the earlier two commands on a clock, run these two commands on a clock. This will give them 1 virtual dollar for every player they kill, but you could easily change the first command below from 1 to 100 or whatever you want to add.

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_pvpKill_min=1] money 1
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_pvpKill_min=1] pvpKill 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that you're thinking of the money that you check with the `/balance` command, which is NOT part of vanilla minecraft, and CANNOT be done with commands. If this is what you mean by 'money', the way to do this is by using a spigot/bukkit server with the Vault plugin and a Mob Kill counting plugin installed. If you don't have spigot, you can try what the other answers are suggesting, but I'm not sure if you'll get what you're looking for.